# Don't run test task - gradle clean build -x test

Tags: testing, gradle, task, alias

I'm trying to find a way to create a task noTestBuild to do the following:

**gradle clean build -x test**

How can I create this. I saw this link which talks about creating alias tasks : https://www.mail-archive.com/user@gradle.codehaus.org/msg09173.html

Is there an easy way to do this using Gradle/Groovy code rather than using type: Exec and calling "sh" or "bash" to call "gradle clean build -x test"

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you are looking for `gradle assemble`

Answer (score 0):

If you're applying the 'java' plugin, then as previously mentioned, 'gradle clean assemble' should achieve the result you're looking for.

However, if you also want to include clean, this might do the job:

```
task noTestBuild(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks=[clean, assemble]
}
```